# 3 Variables into one function javascript? ´Variables are true or false and depending on the outcome I change it to the string

Tags: javascript

```
var one
var two
var three

    if (one === true) {
        var one = "&#10004";
    } else if (one === false){
        var one = "&times";
    }
```

I do not want to write the code out 3 times... please help..

Comment: what function are you referring to? This is very unclear

Comment: What? Are you trying to change three variables at once?

Comment: We need more detail on your problem. Please add clarification to your question since you have only add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve but I'm guessing that you want to find out how to do your commands 3 times without writing the code 3 times.
I'd recommend putting those 3 `var`s into an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) and iterating through them with a `for`-loop ([for-loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)). Hopefully this is what you wanted

```
let one
let two
let three

const numbers = [one, two, three]

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    if (numbers[i]) {
        numbers[i] = "&#10004";
    } else {
        numbers[i] = "&times";
    }
}
```

Or using the map-function:

```
const one = true;
const two = false;
const three = true;

const numbers = [one, two, three];
const [newOne, newTwo, newThree] = numbers.map(x => x ? '&#10004' : '&times');
```

Comment: Or using a simple map: `numb.map(x => x ? '&#10004' : '&times')`.

Comment: Thanks man I cannot vote but this helped me THess!

Comment: No problemo, is it still possible to mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tick below the score though? @007

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), if you have other values than `true` and `false`.

```
const getSign = value => value === true
    ? "&#10004"
    : value === false
        ? "&times"
        : value;
```

If you have only `true` or `false`, you could just check the value and take one of both values.

```
const getSign = value => value
    ? "&#10004"
    : "&times";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write shorthand statement like this:

```
else if (!one){

                 var one = "&times";
              }
```

This sign ! is a logical not, so it is the same as (one === false)

More on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators